# Issue in fetching data from arrays within an array

Tags: parsing, android-volley, get-request

I want to fetch data from a web service but it is showing this error.

```
D/exception: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 3 path $[0]
```

There are two arrays in an array, I tried parsing it but unable to get it, It is showing data in `stringResponse` but don't know why parsing through GSON not working.

[Model Class](https://www.dropbox.com/s/528x4h7b9uiv2ig/ModelClass.txt?dl=0)

**MainClass**

```java
private void getStringResponse() {
    String url = "http://www.mocky.io/v2/5bd7f4683100003508474b3d";
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            url,
            new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    String stringResponse = response.toString();
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    try{
                        ModelOne[] data = gson.fromJson(stringResponse, ModelOne[].class);
                        List<ModelOne.First> first = new ArrayList<>();
                        first = data[0].getZero();
                        Log.d("data", first.get(0).getFullName());
                    } catch (Exception e){
                        Log.d("exception", e.toString());
                    }
                }
            }, new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("error", error.toString());
                }
            });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(request);
}
```

I just need minor guidelines, that how to tackle data when you have arrays within array and how to parse it.
and It was showing that your question has max code that's why I uploaded dropbox link

Comment: I posted a question but no one answered